# FFmpeg doesn't play any audio through Discord.py BOT

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl, discord.py

Here is my code for my Discord bot's play function:

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url:str = None): # DOESN'T WORK, DOWNLOADS BUT DOESN'T PLAY

        ...

        ytdl_options = {
            'format': 'bestaudio/best',
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                'preferredquality': '192',
            }],
        }
        ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_options)

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url))


        if 'entries' in data:
            data = data['entries'][0] # taking top item from a YT playlist

        source = ytdl.prepare_filename(data)

        vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(source)) #play audio
        print(vc.is_playing())
        await ctx.send("Now playing: " + data.get('title')) #now playing
        asyncio.sleep(3)
        print(vc.is_playing())
```

When I call the function, it runs fine and downloads the video from youtube-dl, then sends the message "Now playing: X",  but doesn't play any audio.

I added the two  `print(vc.is_playing())` lines and what is returned in the shell is:

```
True
False
```

So clearly it tries to play the song but immediately fails.

There are no exceptions thrown, so I can't understand why FFmpeg doesn't want to play the audio.

Comment: Try dumping the source variable value and running it through ffmpeg on the console. Most likely you'll see an error there.

Comment: I found out it was simply a Discord error... Changed the server region on Discord and it plays perfectly.